# How to catch PCL_ERROR from RANSAC?

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am trying to use SAC_SEGMENTATION from PCL right now. Sometimes I will get an error like this:
[pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane::optimizeModelCoefficients] Not enough inliers found to support a model (0)! Returning the same coefficients.

How can I catch this error in my code? Unfortunately I could not find much on Google so I was hoping to see if anyone has tried something similar before.